# Save as file .xlsb to .xls from url

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xls

I have a file .xlsb from url, I use this code to download it and save it to .xls file

```
$filename = 'public/files/savedfile.xls';
file_put_contents($filename, fopen($url, 'r'));
```

But it didn't correct format even though it was saved .xls file (correct extension). And when I use phpexcel to read it, phpexcel return an error:

```
 [ErrorException]
 DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Invalid char in CDATA 0x3 in Entity, line: 1
```

How can I Save As this file from url to .xls file (correct extension and format).

P/s: url file [here](http://phx.corporate-ir.net/External.File?item=UGFyZW50SUQ9NjczNjM5fENoaWxkSUQ9MzgxNTk0fFR5cGU9MQ==&t=1)

Comment: `.xlsb` is not the same format as `.xls`, and PHPExcel cannot read `xlsb` files

Comment: see if this [link](http://www.ahowto.net/php/read-and-write-excel-file-using-php-example/) helps you